# TCP/IP default port for sending console messages?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, ip, port

Is there a dedicated port (lower than 1024) specifically for clients to send text based console output to a server? I've googled extensively but to no avail. What's the best port (lower than 1024) for sending text based console output if any?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm going to use telnet (port 23) since that's closest to what I want. Sending console messages to a server from a client. okey dokey thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A port is just a number. You can see [*well known*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_known_port#Well-known_ports) port assignments in `/etc/services`.

You need a server application to be listening on the given port to accept your input. There are number of remote terminal *protocols* and their implementations, among which are [Telnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) (port 23) and [Secure Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell), or SSH (port 22).

The simplest way to test your socket *client* is to setup [`netcat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) on the server to listen on whatever port you want (port is `777` in the example bellow), and then try to connect to it from somewhere else:

```
server:~# nc -l -p 777
```

then

```
client:~$ nc server 777
```

Note that on Unix you normally need super-user (root) rights to bind "privileged", i.e. bellow 1024, ports.

Comment: You'll need Admin permissions on Windows to bind to the well-known ports (<1024) also.